# How to use string from editText in one activity in methods in second activity

Tags: android

Can someone help me with this. I just passed a word from editText to a new activity in onCreate. Now I need to use that word inside private methods of the activity which accepted the word but I can't. I tried declaring word final String variable but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Please use Intent for passing your data to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

in Activty1 write below code to send your string from Activity1 to Activity2

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activty2.class);
intent.putExtra("MY_STRING_KEY", "your_edit_text_value_will_be_here");
startActivity(intent);
```

in Activty2 write below code to get string data from previous activity / Activty1 (in this case it is Activty1.java)

```
String previousActivityString = getIntent().getStringExtra("MY_STRING_KEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways like using bundles , shared pref & recently introduced View Model class. According to me View Model class is the best for future use.
Refer : 
    https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

hope this helps